# How to trigger $onInit or $onChanges implictly in unit testing Angular component controller?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm using Angular 1.5.5 and Jasmine as test framework. Currently I have to do something like this so that the test passes:

```
function createController(bindings) {
    return $componentController('myController', null, bindings);
}

beforeEach(inject(function (_$componentController_) {
    $componentController = _$componentController_;
}));

describe('on pages updated', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        controller = createController({prop1: 0, prop2: 0});
        controller.$onInit(); // you see I have to explitcitly call this $onInit function
    });

    it('should update isSelected and currentPage', function () {
        expect(controller.prop1).toBe(0);
        expect(controller.prop2).toBe(0);

        controller.prop1= 1;
        controller.prop2= 2;
        controller.$onChanges(controller); // and $onChanges here as well

        expect(controller.prop1).toBe(1);
        expect(controller.prop2).toBe(2);
    });

});
```

Comment: Why do you want to trigger it implicitly in the first place? `$onInit` is a lifecycle hook called when the component is mounted. There's no reason for `$componentController` to ever call that function on it's own in unit tests. You should definitely be triggering those things explicitly unless you're testing the component as a whole.

Answer (score 10):

There is an issue in github regarding this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14129

Basically it is working as intended, not calling `$onInit` or `$onChanges` automatically.

> it makes no sense (or low sense) to execute $onInit, I explain it: $componentController is to instance controllers a kind of replacement for $controller, but instead of creating instances of controllers registered by the controllerProvider it creates instances of controllers registered through directives (the ones that satisfies a component definition). So, once you have the instance of the controller, you can call manually $onInit, and all the lifecycle of your controller, the idea is that you are testing a controller, not a directive (and its relationships).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but for testing components I do the following

```
beforeEach(module('templates'));

var element;        
var scope;

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    scope.draw = new ol.source.Vector({ wrapX: false });
    element = angular.element('<custom-element draw="draw"></custom-element>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
}));

var controller;
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $componentController) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    scope.draw = new ol.source.Vector({ wrapX: false });
    controller = $componentController('customElement', {draw: new ol.source.Vector({ wrapX: false })}, { $scope: scope });
}));
```

and $onInit() and $onChanges() get triggered when they should be, by themselves

Comment: Wouldn't this give you a controller that isn't actually associated with the component that you're compiling?

Comment: So it seems to me that your trick is to use the $compile service to also compile the directive, right?

Comment: @DanPantry why should it, you are compiling a component and asking for that components controller

Comment: From what I'm reading here, you're compiling a component and then asking for an instance of that component's controller, but not necessarily the instance of the controller that component was compiled with (if that makes any sense). IOW, `$compile()` is creating a controller and then you're creating *another* controller with `$componentController`. It's the same controller class, but not the same class instance as the one created by `$compile`. I would assume a better way to do this is `angular.element(...).controller()`, which would get you the controller associated with the component.

Answer (score 0):

You would require to take reference of controller from compiled version of element. As shown below:

```
describe('Component: Test Method', function () {

        beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_) {
            scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        }));


        it('should set value of selectedPackage to null after $onChanges event', inject(function ($compile) {
            // Trigger 1st $onChanges
            scope.selectedPackage = 'packageCode';

            var element = angular.element('<select-my-tv selected-package="selectedPackage"></select-my-tv>');
            element = $compile(element)(scope);
            scope.$digest();

            //Extract the Controller reference from compiled element
            var elementController = element.isolateScope().$ctrl;

            // Assert
            expect(elementController.selectedPackage).toBeNull();
        }));
    });
});
```

Comment: But why would you expect `selectedPackage` to be `null`?  I understand that `$onInit` isn't called when you `new`-up a controller, but why is it not called when you render the actual component with `$compile`?  Surely that should trigger all lifecycle hooks.