# How to test properties set in controller.$onInit method in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have a scenario where I initialize some of the variables in controller.$onInit method. How can I test whether these properties are set properly?

Controller

```
 ctrl.$onInit = function () {
    ctrl.devices = _.cloneDeep(ctrl.formDevices);
};
```

Unit test

```
it('should expose device related properties to view', function () {
        expect(controller.devices).toBeDefined();
};
```

Output

[Unit test output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3ijz.png)

Answer (score 3):

You have to explicitly call the $onInit function. $componentController doesn't call this function as it's part of a lifecycle hook, which it doesn't run through.

There are ways for $onInit to be called implicity, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631204/how-to-trigger-oninit-or-onchanges-implictly-in-unit-testing-angular-component).

The easiest way to check if your $onInit function sets the properties correctly would be to call $onInit. After all you're testing whether the $onInit function does it job and not whether AngularJS goes through it's lifecycle hooks.

```
it('should expose device related properties to view', function () {
    controller.$onInit();
    expect(controller.devices).toBeDefined();
};
```